# Set-SPOSite not working for Group enabled SharePoint Online sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, groups

I'm executing the below script to disable one of the document sharing options:

set-sposite -Identity "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/useraccessmanagement" -DisableCompanyWideSharingLinks Disabled

This script is displaying the below error for all Group enabled SharePoint Online sites but for other sites, it is working as expected.

Error Screenshot and Error Text:

[image]

> set-sposite :
>   https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/UserAccessManagement is a
>   Groups site collection. The valid parameters for  this type of site
>   collection are '-Identity', '-AllowSelfServiceUpgrade',
>   '-DefaultLinkPermission', '-DefaultSharingLinkType', 
>   '-DenyAddAndCustomizePages', '-DisableCompanyWideSharingLinks',
>   '-DisableSharingForNonOwners', '-LockState', '-Owner', 
>   '-ResourceQuota', '-ResourceQuotaWarningLevel',
>   '-SandboxedCodeActivationCapability', '-SharingCapability', 
>   '-ShowPeoplePickerSuggestionsForGuestUsers',
>   '-SocialBarOnSitePagesDisabled', '-StorageQuota',
>   '-StorageQuotaReset', and  '-StorageQuotaWarningLevel'. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + set-sposite -Identity "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/useraccessmanageme ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-SPOSite], ServerException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SetSite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your management shell to a current version; I would strongly suggest using the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell/) version for easy updating in the future, if you're currently using the MSI.

You will want to uninstall the MSI version prior to installing the PoSh gallery version.

Comment: Issue resolved after installing latest SharePoint Online Management Shell. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run the PowerShell with SharePoint Online Management Shell.

Get started with SharePoint Online Management Shell for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/set-sposite-lt-url-gt-is-a-groups-site-collection-the-valid/m-p/1182449